# How to use programs with MPI?

Tags: compiling, programming, mpi

Is it possible to use programs with MPI for example blender?
Is it a mpi program by only adding the source file "mpi.h" or is there any way to simply convert an existing program for the use with mpi?
Also virtualbox would be really nice to use it with mpi..

Answer (score 0):

MPI is a library that you compile with your program just like any other programming library. Unless you specifically make calls into the library to use the features of MPI, nothing special will happen.

In addition, MPI programs are launched differently than regular programs. Instead of just running the program normally from the command line

```
./a.out <arguments>
```

you use the MPI launcher which starts the appropriate number of processes (in this example, 4)

```
mpiexec -n 4 ./a.out
```

If you want to learn more about MPI, you should probably go find some tutorial websites and/or books. Explaining the whole thing doesn't really fit into this format.